# Cakephp 3 Digest authentication

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, stateless, digest-authentication

I have attempted to use digest authentication with cakephp 3 to make a scalable system. The client is only asked for a password when needed, but the details entered do not permit access, instead the dialog requesting credentials pops up again. Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!

AppController::initialize()

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Digest' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password_hash'],
                'userModel' => 'Users',
                'finder' => 'auth'
            ],
        ],
        'authError' => 'incorrect username or password',
        'storage' => 'Memory',
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
    ]);
```

UsersTable:

```
    public function beforeSave(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
{
    $entity = $event->data['entity'];

    // Make a password for digest auth.
    $entity->password_hash = DigestAuthenticate::password(
        $entity->username, 
        $entity->plain_password,
        env('SERVER_NAME')
    );

    $entity->created = Time::now();
    return true;
}

public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->select(['id', 'username', 'password_hash']);
    return $query;
}
```

Edit: removed code from entity

I decided to delve into the digest getuser function ([Function code](https://api.cakephp.org/3.1/source-class-Cake.Auth.DigestAuthenticate.html#96-123)) and output some data into my unauthorized page so I can see whats going on.

```
$Password: 8a3575d301f04f08dd461f93e3d55a21 
$digest[username]: James  
$digest['response']: 4fa261678c753da8e78e4bf98057fd72 
$hash: a627c3e68061937e454c321d55e986d3
$request->env('ORIGINAL_REQUEST_METHOD'): GET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it turns out I made a really silly mistake!
Changes:

```
$entity->password_hash = DigestAuthenticate::password(
    $entity->username, 
    $entity->password_hash, // was plain_password which was not in my model!
    env('SERVER_NAME')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the _setPassword function from the entity. The password will be hashed and later on this hash will be used on the DigestAuthentication, instead of the required plaintext.

I'd additionally refactor and remove the password creation from the beforeSave and put it to the entity similar to what you did with the passwordHasher now...
Keep in mind, you need to update the digest on _setUsername *and* _setPassword in this case!

Comment: I am just thinking about how I could do this from the setUsername, as I would not know the password needed to change the digesthash value!

Comment: I just cleared my database and tested this again and sadly it is still not working. I am able to consistently get the same hash in the database but the authentication does not seem to get matching hashes when the correct credentials are supplied. Any ideas?